# Viewing Apex file names in VS Code before retrieving it without using ForceCode extension

Tags: vs-code, forcecode

Earlier I was using ForceCode extension in VS Code. It had a nice feature to retrieve files ( Apex ) from server. You enter characters in the search box and it will show filtered list of Apex in a dropdown with check boxes. This was a nice way of quickly browsing Apex files on server without actually retrieving it.  Now I have switched completely to SF Extension pack for my work. Say, I don't know the actual file name I want to retrieve from server and I want to be able to browse just like ForceCode did and then click/select file.  How is this done using SF extnsions alone? Is there a Retrieve file menu option for SFDX in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Salesforce Extension Pack** has that feature called "Org Browser". Once you create a project and authorize an org you will be able to see the list of all metadata components in the org browser.

In the org browser, you get two buttons, one to refresh the list of components, and the second one to retrieve those by clicking the downloading button.

If expanded, you can also retrieve individual metadata items, like apex class, lwc, etc.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing that in mine. Is that something you have to explicitly add or activate, or be in a certain context to see?  I opened the Command Pallete (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) and found and clicked on _View: Show Org Browser_; but I saw nothing appear.

Comment: It's in the left sidebar. As shown in the above image. @Moonpie

Comment: This feature is definitely going to be a productivity booster for developers as it shows not just Apex and LWC but all metadata. Developer can see all configurable metadata without logging in to  an org through front end!!

Comment: @vinod Indeed, also you don't need to change the package.xml

Comment: It does not appear in mine. I did look there first! :)  I am on Version 49.1.0, which is indicated is the current one.  You did not have to do anything to "activate" it?

Comment: try to update sf cli, and sf extension pack @Moonpie